# Pytorch parallel inference

Tags: pytorch

I have tuned a Bert Model for Sentiment Analysis and now I want to make inference. I have tried several methods to increase the performance but still there is like no improvement.
The most obvious solution was that, I have divided my input data to be predicted to 10 parts and sent each group in parallel. Also I am loading the model for each parallel process. So obviously there should be an improvement, but there is none. Is this a problem about pytorch ?

Comment: Do you have multiple GPUs? What is exactly the bottleneck?

Comment: No I am not trying to do inference in gpu just cpu but in parallel. Then I have even called the script with different input files from terminal, and I saw no improvement.

Comment: Did you check if your CPU isn't at max processing with only one part?

Comment: When I run only single process it uses only 25% memory and there are 8 cpus 5 of them are running,